# Can I throw error when client request non-selected-field on entitiy

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, typeorm, dto

On my user entity, I set property 'password' with {select: false} options (to prevent client from accessing their passwords).

```
@InputType({ isAbstract: true })
@ObjectType()
@Entity('User')
export class User {

  @Column({ unique: true })
  @Field(() => String)
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @Column({ select: false })
  @Field(() => String)
  @IsString()
  password: string;
}
```

And on my resolver and service, I created a `findUser` function to `findUser` in the database with the email.

```
//on resolvers
  @Query(() => UserOutput)
  async findUser(@Args('email') email: string): Promise<UserOutput> {
    return this.userService.findUser(email);
  }

//on service: this.userService.findUser(email) on resolvers findUser function
//userDB is typeorm things that connected to User table in postgres DB.
  async findUser(email: string): Promise<UserOutput> {
    try {
      const user = await this.userDB.findOne(email);
      return user ? { sucess: true, user } : {sucess: false, error: 'User not found'};
    } catch (error) {
      return { sucess: false, error: 'Unexpected error from findUser' };
    }
  }

//userOutput DTO
@ObjectType()
export class UserOuput {
  @Field(() => Boolean)
  @IsBoolean()
  sucess: boolean;

  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  error?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @Field(() => User, { nullable: true, defaultValue: null })
  user?: User;
}
```

When accessing the GraphQL playground and entering the `findUser` command as follows (that contain property of 'password' that is {select: false} field):

```
query {
  findUser(email: "test@email.com" ) {
    sucess
    error
    user {
      email
      password
    }
  }
}
```

And I get an errors object and data as follows:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.password.",
      "locations": [...],
      "path": [...],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [...]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "findUser": {
      "sucess": true,
      "error": null,
      "user": null
    }
  }
}
```

And this code is not wrong. because we have given the correct email, and have successfully found the user. However, `{success: true}` is wrong because the user object could not be retrieved by using the `findUser` command with the password that is non-selected-field.

How can I return `{success: false, error: "something_error_message", user: null}` when client request non-selected-field like 'password'?

Comment: the problem is that select:false is a typeorm directive and not a type-graphq one. So in the schema, it is still mandatory. I would either remove the @Field in the user class or make it nullable as in your dto.

Comment: @Jerome is right. Moreover, the possibility for a user to return a password is a bad practice. Simply don't show it in the schema and you are good to go :)

Comment: @Jerome thanks for answer. i will try it.

Comment: @carlo you're right, but it depends if you are using graphql also in the backend to query the database and check if password is valid. you then need to get the password back. decrypt it with a private passphrase or key that is known only by the backend. So it really depends on the usecase. but in any case, the password should be crypted also in the database